# Python Visualization to show proper graph

Tags: python, pandas

How we can Draw a chart that shows the types of complaints in each city in a single chart
where different colors show the different types of complaints

Column name `"City"` is having multiple cities and columns name `"Complaint Type"` is having multiple type of complaints

```
pivot_t=df.pivot_table(index='Complaint Type',columns='City',values='Unique Key')
pivot_t.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

it is showing this chart which is i believe not correct can anyone hlep me the code how to achieve the correct graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do:

```
pivot_t = df.pivot_table(index='Complaint Type', columns='City', aggfunc='size')
# OR
pivot_t = pd.crosstab(df['Complaint Type'], df['City'])

ax = pivot_t.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(2023)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Complaint Type': rng.choice(list('ABCDEFG'), 50),
                   'City': rng.choice(list('VWXYZ'), 50)})
```

Comment: hi Corralien, i have used this code  pivot_t = pd.crosstab(df['Complaint Type'], df['City'])

ax = pivot_t.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show() but still it is over lapping issue coming so any idea why it is coming